# Using a loop to generate new arrays from elements of pre-existing arrays [Python]

Tags: python, arrays

trying to achieve the following in a "for loop"
I have several arrays

```
a1=[a,b,c,d,e]
a2=[f,g,h,i,j]
a3=[k,l,m,n,o]
```

Using the loop, I hope to achieve new arrays

```
b1=[a,f,k]
b2=[b,g,l]....
b5=[e,j,o]
```

This is what I have :

```
totala=a1,a2,a3

for x in range (0,len(a1)):
    print([item[x] for item in totala])
```

this allows me to output what I want:[a,f,k] [b,g,l]...
However, i'm not entirely clear how to create the new arrays.

Any help would be useful! 
 
Cheers

Comment: use `zip()` and store values in a `dict` rather than dynamically creating new variables

Comment: What do you mean? you *are* creating the new **lists**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to create variables from the printed arrays. It's possible but I think, it's not the proper way to do that since your script would be very static (maybe you want to use a sixth character in the arrays. Then you would have to change your whole processings of the resulting b - variables). So I suggest you using a dictionary instead:

```
b_dict = {}
for x in range (0,len(a1)):
    print([item[x] for item in totala])
    b_dict[x+1] = [item[x] for item in totala] # i.e. 1: [a,f,k]
```

Afterwards you could process all your b's in a loop:

```
for key in b_dict:
    pass #process your b keys and b_dict[key] - values
```

If you really want to use b - **variables** you could do something like this:

```
for x in range (0,len(a1)):
    print([item[x] for item in totala])
    globals()["b" + str(x+1)] = [item[x] for item in totala]
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what i'm looking for.
Cheers on the heads up for dictionaries. Just started learning coding and have not really used dictionaries for problems before. thanks once again

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. Welcome to the world of coding ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`.

```
map(list,zip(a1,a2,a3))
```

Execution

```
In [6]: for item in map(list,zip(a1,a2,a3)):
   ...:     print item
   ...:     
['a', 'f', 'k']
['b', 'g', 'l']
['c', 'h', 'm']
['d', 'i', 'n']
['e', 'j', 'o']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several different methods,
one way:

```
result=[]
for a1_i, a2_i, a3_i in zip(a1,a2,a3):
    result.append([a1_i, a2_i, a3_i])
```

in this way you get a list where each element is the triplet you were looking for.

Another way is convert the lists in a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
a1=np.array(a1)
a2=np.array(a2)
a3=np.array(a3)
a=np.array([a1,a2,a3])
```

Now if you read `a` by rows yuo get the original a1,a2,a3; instead if you read `a` by columns you get your triplet, try printing:

```
print(a[:, 0])
print(a.T)
```